# hadoop what is the "__distcpSplit__" file in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

While I used Distcp tool to copy files through different cluster, I found some unusual files with `__distcpSplit__` in suffix. What is this? The original file does not have such suffix. I also notice that the source file is opened by other process, but why this result?

Comment: Precisely, the name is ****.__distcpSplit__0.20210101

Answer (score 0):

If you pass arg blocksPerChunk > 0, it will split big files into multi chunks, each size of them is blockSize * blocksPerChunk, and when distcp is finishing, output committer will concat these files to the final target file at commit stage.

Comment: Yes,what you said is right.But I also find distcp has a bug.There is a situation in which distcp is copying single file as a whole without spliting the file  that is written during the copying time.Distcp will not delete these chunk files.